# What linux command should I use to get a long list of items in current directory, sorted by size such that the biggest items appear last?

Tags: linux

On Linux, how do I derive a long list of items sorted by size (largest to smallest)?

Is this correct:

```
$ ls -laShr /var/~
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all files and sort them by size, use the -S option. By default, it displays output in descending order (biggest to smallest in size).

```
$ ls -laS /var/~
```

And to sort in reverse order, add the -r flag as follows.

```
$ ls -laShr /var/~
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use

```
$ ls -lShr /var/
```

l- for long listing
S- for sorting by size(default descending)
h- for human-readable format
r- for a reverse sort